# How to execute awk command in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I have an awk command that extracts the 16th column from 3rd line in a csv file and prints the first 4 characters.

```
awk -F"," 'NR==3{print $16}' sample.csv|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'
```

This works fine.

But when I execute it from a shell script, I get and error

```
#!/bin/ksh
YEAR=awk -F"," 'NR==3{print $16}' sample.csv|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'
```

Error message:

```
 -F,: not found
```

Comment: did you try `YEAR=$(your awk stuff|sed|awk|sed|awk...)`

Comment: glad to help. btw, your `awk|sed|awk` combination worked, however it is like killing a fly by nuclear bomb, and 3 nuclear bombs... there must be room to improve.   well, first thing is to make it work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to assign the output of a command to a variable, as shown below:

```
YEAR=$(awk -F"," 'NR==3{print $16}' sample.csv|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

you are asking the shell to do :

```
VAR=value command [arguments...]
```

which means: launch `command` but pass it the `VAR=value` environment first
(ex:   `LC_ALL=C grep '[0-9]*' /some/file.txt`  : will `grep` a number in `file.txt` (and this with the `LC_ALL` variable set to `C` just for the duration of the call of `grep`)

So here : you ask the shell to launch the `-F","` command (ie, `-F,` once the shell interpret the `","` into `,`  with arguments `'NR==3..........` and with the variable `YEAR` set to the value `awk`  for the duration of the command invocation.

Just replace it with :

```
#!/bin/ksh
YEAR="$(awk -F',' 'NR==3{print $16}' sample.csv|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'|awk '{print substr($0,1,4)}')"
```

(I didn't try it, but I hope they work for you and your sample.csv file)

(Note that you use "0" to match character position 1, which works in many awk implementation but not all (ie most (but not all) assume 1 when you write 0))

Comment: you better enclose the whole command substition within "" as I did, as otherwise if it returns more than 1 word you'll end up invoking another `var=word1  word2 ....` invocation of command `word2 ....` with value of `var` set to `word1`

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you want to extract the year from the 16th field, which might contain leading spaces. You can accomplish it by calling AWK once:

```
YEAR=$(awk -F, 'NR==3{sub(/^[ \t]*/, "", $16); print ">" substr($16,1,4) "<" }')
```

Better yet, you don't even have to use awk. Since you are already writing shell script, let's do it all in shell script:

```
{ read line; read line; read line; } < sample.csv # Get the third line
IFS=, set $line   # Breaks line into comma-separated fields
IFS=" " set ${16} # Trick to remove leading spaces, field 16 becomes field 1
YEAR=${1:0:4}     # Extract the first 4 char from field 1
```

Comment: good advice on the awk script, but don't do the shell thing as it's error prone (e.g. will fail if "line" contains a backslash or various other characters) and cumbersome (try to modify it to work on line 67 instead of line 3).

Comment: I agree regarding the error-prone part. Modifying to work with lines other than 3 is not that hard.

Comment: Nothing in software is "that hard". It's only software. The point is though you would not write 67 "read line" statements so even if you're happy having 3 duplicated, hard-coded statements in THIS script, you'd need to re-write the script at some point just to deal with a different line number, hence my claim that it's cumbersome and my advice not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
year=$(awk -F, 'NR==3{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$16); print substr($16,1,4); exit }' sample.csv)
```

Comment: Thank you all for you wonderful inputs. I am having a great day!